# Is it harmful to declare union with SIMD types?

Tags: c, simd, intrinsics

I wrote a SIMD wrapper. To ease the use of different types, I made it as a union:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

union SIMDType16
{
    __m128 simd_by_float;
    __m128i simd_by_int;
    __m128d simd_by_double;
}
```

However, from some place I heard that the type information in Intel SIMD intrisics is related to hardware usage. So, does my definition of union cause potential effect loss?

Comment: I would say no, your method seems to be a standard method of  wrapping different types and I've seen it being used else where. I have also heard people has had compile issues where the __m128 has already been defined as an union, but I expect that might of been programmer error - as it's normally typedef'ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely fine, except of course that there are plenty of reasons why unions can get you into trouble, totally independent of SIMD types. For example, if you assign to sims_by_float and then read simd_by_double, you invoke undefined behaviour and your program can crash. See [C++ Undefined behaviour with unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273320/c-undefined-behaviour-with-unions)

Since there are intrinsics that convert between various vector types (and generate no code) I wouldn't use that kind of union unless there is a very, very, very good reason to do so.

Comment: Question is tagged `C` though, and I believe that, since C99, this kind of type punning via unions is allowed.