# Can't i typecast a class of size 8 bytes to uint64_t?

Tags: c++, casting, explicit-conversion

Suppose we have below code:

```
class A {
        uint32_t X;
        uint32_t Y;
};

int main ()
{
    A a;
    uint64_t num  = (uint64_t)a;
}
```

The compiler gives error: "Cannot convert from A to uint64_t. No User define conversion operator defined."

Is the error expected and if yes, why?

Comment: Have you considered using a `union` ?

Comment: C/C++ has `union` to do this

Comment: In case, i do not want to union? what are the alternatives?

Comment: @AbhishekJain in case you do not want to do it properly you can shoot your leg by yourself.

Comment: @AbhishekJain Use `memcpy( &num, &a, sizeof( num ) );`.  It's still dangerous.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: You can't assume that your class is actually 8 bytes.  It may have vtable or padding.  You can't do this.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That is undefined behavior

Comment: @NathanOliver, I know.  But if he **knows** his class is 8 bytes, it will work.  Admittedly it's playing with fire, which is why I just posted it as a comment.

Comment: Yes, i am sure that my class is 8 bytes.

Comment: @AbhishekJain - On what hardware?  Some hardware has alignment restrictions that could force your class to be larger than 8 bytes even if it only has 8 bytes of actual data in it.

Comment: Have you tried: `num = ((uint64_t) x << 32) | y;` ? You might be surprised at what the compiler generates, if it's satisfied with endianness, POD type layout, alignment issues, etc. Other approaches, like unions, risk violating strict aliasing rules, etc. (assume `x` is the high half in this example).

Comment: @AndrewHenle you posted as comment because you know you cannot be punished for improper answer? nice

Comment: @BrettHale `union` would violate strict aliasing rule? what?

Comment: Union solutions are UB. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273320/c-undefined-behaviour-with-unions etc.etc.etc

Comment: @Slava What?  Wow, you really think like that?  No, I posted it as a comment **because** it's undefined behavior but it does do what the questioner wanted given the constraints he placed in his question,

Comment: @AndrewHenle it is either UB or does do whatever

Comment: @AbhishekJain - of course, you'd want to use C++ style casts in the example I provided.

Comment: @deviantfan: I was pretty sure a union solution was the correct way of doing things, in order to avoid e.g. strict aliasing optimizations breaking the intent of the programmer?

Comment: @ErikAlapää union type-punning is a common compiler extension, there's even a note about it in the standard IIRC.

Comment: @Quentin: Exactly, union type-punning will work, and any compiler writer breaking it would break a lot of well-written low-level code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly copy the 32 bits of one value to the upper 32 bits of the 64-bit value, and the other 32 bits to the lower 32 bits of the 64-bit value.

All other methods are technically undefined behavior (although if you **know** your implementation details well enough, they can work).

```
class A
{
    uint32_t X;
    uint32_t Y;
    uint64_t to64()
    {
        // convert X and Y to unsigned 64-bit ints
        uint64_t x64 = X;
        uint64_t y64 = Y;
        // left-shift the 64-bit X 32 bits
        x64 <<= 32;

        // return the sum
        return( x64 + y64 );
    }
};
```

You can do it with much less code, but this shows what you need to do in a step-by-step way.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the 'endianness' of your representation. If you want `x` to be the high word and `y` the low word, you could add a cast operator to your class:

```
explicit operator uint64_t () const noexcept
{
    return ((static_cast<uint64_t>(X) << 32) | Y);
}
```

A `'(uint64_t) obj'` or (ideally) `'static_cast<uint64_t>(obj)'` will call this method. `explicit` prevents it being called implicitly - which is probably the dumbest thing I've said all day - but it prevents [surprises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean). Extra points if you use `<cstdint>` and `std::uint64_t`.

Answer (score -2):

Definitely undefined behavior, but try

```
uint64_t num  = *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t *>(&a);
```

Comment: is it UB provided that `sizeof(a) <= sizeof(uint64_t)`?

Comment: @Tomasz UB is UB, regardless.  That doesn't mean for your specific compiler/target that it doesn't consistently do what you desire.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: you're right, my bad; I 'm just trying to figure out which part of this line is the UB excatly